# How do I add a class with main function JavaExec task?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project managed with Gradle with a second class with a main function in it. I want to be able execute this particular main function separately from the command line.

I have the following in the build.gradle file:

```
task runFunction(type:JavaExec) {
   main = 'com.company.project.secondclass'
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

I then run the following command in a terminal:

```
gradle runFunction
```

I then get the following error in the resulting output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.project.secondclass
```

What am I missing which is stopping the second main function being executed?

Comment: Does `build/classes/main/com/company/project/secondclass.class` exist ?

Comment: Besides, `secondclass` should start with a capital letter